# What is inside (how to decompose) an affine warp_matrix

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform

My question is related to an other question I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463722/how-to-use-warp-matrix-from-cv2-findtransformecc-with-cv2-transform). but here I'm trying to understand more precisely the composition of an warp_matrix obtained with cv2.getAffineTransform. 
I found  in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/417813) how to decompose an affine tranformation matrix and especilly how to get the angle of rotation

But when using the example from [the OpenCV Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) I obtain two different angles of rotation.

the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pts1 = np.float32([[50,50],[200,50],[50,200]])
pts2 = np.float32([[10,100],[200,50],[100,250]])

M = cv2.getAffineTransform(pts1,pts2)

theta0=np.degrees(np.arctan(-M[0,1]/M[0,0]))
theta1=np.degrees(np.arctan(M[1,0]/M[1,1]))

print(theta0)
print(theta1)
```

produce :

```
-25.3461759419
-18.4349488229
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similarity transforms (which are represented by a combination of scaling, rotating, and translating) are a *subset* of affine transformations. Affine transformations are arbitrary 2x3 matrices and as such do not have to decompose into separate scaling, rotation, and transformation matrices.

If you don't want to have an affine transformation but a similarity transform so that you can do this decomposition, then you will need to use a different function to compute similarity transforms instead of affine.

If you are using OpenCV 3.2.0+ (4.0+ included as well) then you can use [`cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D()` (docs)](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d). If you're on a previous version, you can use [`cv2.estimateRigidTransform()` (docs)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48).

From the docs on `estimateAffinePartial2D()`, the estimated transformation matrix is

```
cos(θ) * s   -sin(θ) * s    t_x
sin(θ) * s    cos(θ) * s    t_y
```

Where `θ` is the rotation angle, `s` the scaling factor and `t_x`, `t_y` are translations in x, y axes respectively.

The result here can be decomposed as per the answer you linked.

```py
>>> M, inliers = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(pts1, pts2)
>>> M
array([[  1.26666667,   0.33333333, -70.        ],
       [ -0.33333333,   1.26666667,  53.33333333]])
```

You can even see here that the diagonals of the first two columns are obviously related as they should be for a rotation, but just to double check:

```py
>>> theta0 = np.degrees(np.arctan2(-M[0,1], M[0,0]))
>>> theta1 = np.degrees(np.arctan2(M[1,0], M[1,1]))
>>> print(theta0)
-14.7435628365
>>> print(theta1)
-14.7435628365
```

---

Note that the [answer you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati/417813#417813) references [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/extracting-rotation-scale-values-from-2d-transformation-matrix/13165#13165) from a different question. There is a slight difference from the matrix we got here and the matrix discussed there---in the version above there is only a single scale factor `s`, but in the version linked, there's two scale factors, `s_x` and `s_y`. This effectively leaves *five* degrees of freedom, namely the variables

```
s_x, s_y, θ, t_x, t_y
```

A similarity transform has *four* degrees of freedom, and a full affine transform has *six*. I don't actually know if the type with five degrees of freedom is a commonly used one; I haven't seen it discussed in the image stitching/photogrammetry literature that I've read (though mathematically it's of course still a valid subset of affine transformations). I just point this out since it's a discrepancy between my answer and the one you linked, but in practice I don't think you will see that type of transform used.